# Update Values with Function in PHP with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

i have a panel to confirm the users, there can be multiple selections with option select exc. I did the delete users part and its working perfect but with updating them to  confirmed, i have some problems, i cant update the value of confirmation, here are the codes:

The Update Code from Panel :

```
if(isset($_POST["members"])) {
$members = $_POST["members"];
while(list($index, $member_id) = each($members)) {
confirmMembers($member_id); }
$msg = "Success";} 
else { $msg = "Error"; }
```

The confirmMembers Function :

```
function confirmMembers($member_id) {
global $db, $log;

try {
$confirm_member = "UPDATE `members` SET `confirmed` = 1 WHERE `member_id` = :member_id  LIMIT 1";
$confirm_member_do = $db->prepare($confirm_member);
$confirm_member_do->bindParam(':member_id', $member_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$confirm_member_do->execute();
return true;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
$log->logError($e." - ".basename(__FILE__));
return false;
}
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error, or what happens?

Comment: getting success message but not updating in database, doesn't updating the 0 value to 1

Comment: Does `var_dump($confirm_member_do->errorInfo())` return anything?

Comment: Yes something like this : array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }

Comment: Are you sure the $_POST['members'] is ana rray? It's coming from an HTML form that has name="members[]"?

Comment: yes it is, i have a delete function just the same function except the difference delete update thingies, below this and its working.

Comment: What's the value of `$member_id` inside function? Have you tried to use `intval($member_id)` in `bindParam` instead of bold `$member_id`?

Comment: @Passerby tried now and no luck with that too. but as i said i have the same function for delete except its delete `members` where `member_id` = :member_id , only the `confirmed` row is the difference but i fetch the row from db where i call the function, but how cant i update it i dont get it

Comment: That's puzzling...did you accidentally put yourself in a transaction? Whats `$db->inTransaction()` before `execute`, and `$confirm_member_do->rowCount()` after `execute`?

Comment: i did what you said but got success message without again not changing value 0 to 1, after that also did `print_r($confirm_member_do-> rowCount());` and that returned 0 in `print_r`

Comment: You'll always get success message, even if it fails to update any rows - so that's not really a clue. Can you echo out member_id, just to be sure on that one?

Comment: it echos out the true member_id. seems like no problem with that, should i fetch the confirmed row in while loop ?

Comment: Are you sure there's an existing row with the member_id you're passing in? Try doing a SELECT before the UPDATE.

Comment: i tried what you said but still no luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last i found the mistake, for all who may make the same mistake, confirmed row is an enum value and must be equal to '1' instead of 1, that fixed the error and now it's working.

```
 $confirm_member = "UPDATE `members` SET `confirmed` = '1' WHERE `member_id` = :member_id  LIMIT 1";
```

Thanks for all who replied.